# ride.py: command not found

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, robotframework

I installed Robot Framework successfully using pip.
When I use the command `robot --version`, I get this:

> Robot Framework 3.0.2 (Python 3.5.2 on linux)

But when I try to use the command `ride.py`, I get this error:

> ride.py: command not found

Comment: What if you change your dir to where ride lives `cd WherePythonLives\Scripts` and then run `python ride.py`

Comment: You are just typing `ride.py` into your terminal? You probably need `python ride.py`

Answer (score 1):

try to use full syntax of a callable file, by using: 
 `python ride.py`.

Answer (score 1):

RIDE does not support Python 3 yet. Seeing as you're using Python 3.5, I'm suspecting RIDE wasn't installed at all, and therefore, you cannot execute it of course.

Try re-installing RIDE, using the following command, and watch out for error messages. You may also want to check in the `scripts` directory of your Python installation if `ride.py` is present.

```
pip install robotframework-ride
```

If you insist on using RIDE, you'll need to get Python 2.7. What you could do is setting up a side installation of Python 2.7 to use RIDE and keep Python 3.5 as your main Python installation.

FYI, while Robot Framework itself is Python 3 compatible, not all of it's ecosystem has been ported to Python 3 yet. You should consider this before going further in your tests development.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1. First check the robot framework installation version through "pip freeze" at cmd prompt.
2. if you find any version like " robotframework==3.1.1", then uninstall through this command `pip uninstall robotframework`.
3. then again check through pip freeze command for confirmation.
4. then install through this command `pip install robotframework-ride`.
5. After successfully install you can check **ride.py** is available at `C:\Python27\Scripts`.
6. for the RIDE type in command prompt `ride.py`.